# ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a deployed pytorch model using sagemaker. When I tried to get prediction, i got the error.

```
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-12a076043f54> in <module>
----> 1 predictor.predict(np.moveaxis(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0),-1,1))

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id)
    159             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
    160         )
--> 161         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    162         return self._handle_response(response)
    163 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    506                 )
    507             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 508             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    509 
    510         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    909             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    910             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 911             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    912         else:
    913             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from primary with message "Your invocation timed out while waiting for a response from container primary. Review the latency metrics for each container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.".
```

In cloud watch i could not find much details.
This is the snippet of error from cloud watch.

```
2022-11-19T17:37:23,004 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager - Initializing plugins manager...
2022-11-19T17:37:23,112 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - 
Torchserve version: 0.6.0
TS Home: /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Current directory: /
Temp directory: /home/model-server/tmp
Number of GPUs: 1
Number of CPUs: 4
Max heap size: 3346 M
Python executable: /opt/conda/bin/python3.8
Config file: /etc/sagemaker-ts.properties
Inference address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Management address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Metrics address: http://127.0.0.1:8082
Model Store: /.sagemaker/ts/models
Initial Models: model=/opt/ml/model
Log dir: /logs
Metrics dir: /logs
Netty threads: 0
Netty client threads: 0
Default workers per model: 1
Blacklist Regex: N/A
Maximum Response Size: 6553500
Maximum Request Size: 6553500
Limit Maximum Image Pixels: true
Prefer direct buffer: false
Allowed Urls: [file://.*|http(s)?://.*]
Custom python dependency for model allowed: false
Metrics report format: prometheus
Enable metrics API: true
Workflow Store: /.sagemaker/ts/models
Model config: N/A
2022-11-19T17:37:23,119 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager -  Loading snapshot serializer plugin...
2022-11-19T17:37:23,145 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Loading initial models: /opt/ml/model
2022-11-19T17:37:23,148 [WARN ] main org.pytorch.serve.archive.model.ModelArchive - Model archive version is not defined. Please upgrade to torch-model-archiver 0.2.0 or higher
2022-11-19T17:37:23,148 [WARN ] main org.pytorch.serve.archive.model.ModelArchive - Model archive createdOn is not defined. Please upgrade to torch-model-archiver 0.2.0 or higher
2022-11-19T17:37:23,151 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelManager - Model model loaded.
2022-11-19T17:37:23,164 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Inference server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
2022-11-19T17:37:23,260 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Inference API bind to: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2022-11-19T17:37:23,261 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Metrics server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
2022-11-19T17:37:23,274 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Metrics API bind to: http://127.0.0.1:8082
Model server started.
2022-11-19T17:37:23,558 [WARN ] pool-3-thread-1 org.pytorch.serve.metrics.MetricCollector - worker pid is not available yet.
2022-11-19T17:37:24,078 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - CPUUtilization.Percent:0.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,078 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Listening on port: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-11-19T17:37:24,079 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskAvailable.Gigabytes:24.612472534179688|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,079 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUsage.Gigabytes:27.375789642333984|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - [PID]91
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUtilization.Percent:52.7|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Torch worker started.
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUMemoryUtilization.Percent:0.0|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Python runtime: 3.8.13
2022-11-19T17:37:24,080 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUMemoryUsed.Megabytes:0|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,081 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUUtilization.Percent:0|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,081 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryAvailable.Megabytes:14061.58984375|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,081 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUsed.Megabytes:1352.25|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,082 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUtilization.Percent:10.7|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879444
2022-11-19T17:37:24,087 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Connecting to: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-11-19T17:37:24,099 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Connection accepted: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000.
2022-11-19T17:37:24,105 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req. to backend at: 1668879444105
2022-11-19T17:37:24,149 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - model_name: model, batchSize: 1
2022-11-19T17:37:25,123 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-2 ACCESS_LOG - /169.254.178.2:42826 "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 22
2022-11-19T17:37:25,124 [INFO ] pool-2-thread-2 TS_METRICS - Requests2XX.Count:1|#Level:Host|#hostname:container-0.local,timestamp:1668879445
2022-11-19T17:37:25,438 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Created a temporary directory at /home/model-server/tmp/tmp19tgs3l6
2022-11-19T17:37:25,438 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Writing /home/model-server/tmp/tmp19tgs3l6/_remote_module_non_scriptable.py
2022-11-19T17:37:25,814 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Backend worker process died.
2022-11-19T17:37:25,814 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-19T17:37:25,814 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 210, in <module>
2022-11-19T17:37:25,815 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     worker.run_server()
2022-11-19T17:37:25,815 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-5-1 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - 9000 Worker disconnected. WORKER_STARTED
2022-11-19T17:37:25,816 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 181, in run_server
2022-11-19T17:37:25,816 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     self.handle_connection(cl_socket)
2022-11-19T17:37:25,817 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: model, error: Worker died.
2022-11-19T17:37:25,817 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 139, in handle_connection
2022-11-19T17:37:25,817 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     service, result, code = self.load_model(msg)
2022-11-19T17:37:25,817 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 104, in load_model
2022-11-19T17:37:25,818 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     service = model_loader.load(
2022-11-19T17:37:25,818 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - terminateIOStreams() threadName=W-9000-model_1.0-stderr
2022-11-19T17:37:25,818 [WARN ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - terminateIOStreams() threadName=W-9000-model_1.0-stdout
2022-11-19T17:37:25,819 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Retry worker: 9000 in 1 seconds.
2022-11-19T17:37:25,819 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_loader.py", line 151, in load
2022-11-19T17:37:25,820 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Stopped Scanner - W-9000-model_1.0-stdout
2022-11-19T17:37:27,539 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Listening on port: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-11-19T17:37:27,547 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - [PID]123
2022-11-19T17:37:27,548 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Torch worker started.
2022-11-19T17:37:27,548 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Connecting to: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-11-19T17:37:27,549 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Python runtime: 3.8.13
2022-11-19T17:37:27,551 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Connection accepted: /home/model-server/tmp/.ts.sock.9000.
2022-11-19T17:37:27,551 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req. to backend at: 1668879447551
2022-11-19T17:37:27,575 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - model_name: model, batchSize: 1
2022-11-19T17:37:28,408 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stderr org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Stopped Scanner - W-9000-model_1.0-stderr
2022-11-19T17:37:28,763 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Created a temporary directory at /home/model-server/tmp/tmpd_bxvf51
2022-11-19T17:37:28,764 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Writing /home/model-server/tmp/tmpd_bxvf51/_remote_module_non_scriptable.py
2022-11-19T17:37:29,150 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Backend worker process died.
2022-11-19T17:37:29,151 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-19T17:37:29,151 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py", line 210, in <module>
2022-11-19T17:37:29,150 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-5-2 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - 9000 Worker disconnected.
```

I have added test function in the script also

```
def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    logging.info('input function')
    assert request_content_type=='application/json'
    data = json.loads(request_body)['inputs']
    data = torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    logging.info('input shape',data.shape)
    return data    
    
    
def model_fn(model_dir):
    logging.info('load function')
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = OurCNNModel()
    with open(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.pth"), "rb") as f:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(f))
    model=model.to(device)
    logging.info('model loaded')
    return model

def predict_fn(input_object, model):
    logging.info('pred function')
    with torch.no_grad():
        prediction = model(input_object)
    logging.info('model preds',prediction)
    return prediction
```

But i can see these logging info to get an idea where the issue is.

Comment: The problem is before the logs you posted. Even though there are many, can you enter them from the beginning until the worker dies?

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano i have updated